# Python: get value of property

Tags: python, properties

I have this Python 2 code:

```
class VKHandshakeChecker:

    def __getAnswers(self):
        return self.__answers

    def __getStatus(self):
        return self.__status    

    def __init__(self,vkapi,maxDepth=6):
        isinstance(vkapi,VKApi.VKApi)
        self.vkapi = vkapi
        self.__maxDepth=maxDepth
        self.__answers = list()
        self.__status = 'IDLE'
        self.status = property(VKHandshakeChecker.__getStatus)
        self.answers = property(VKHandshakeChecker.__getAnswers)
```

I want to get `answers` property. But when I execute this code:

```
checker = VKHandshakeChecker.VKHandshakeChecker(api)
print(checker.status)
```

I get `<property object at 0x02B55450>`, not `IDLE`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put descriptors (like a `property` object) on the instance. You *have* to use them on the class.

Simply use `property` as a decorator:

```
class VKHandshakeChecker:
    @property
    def answers(self):
        return self.__answers

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self.__status    

    def __init__(self,vkapi,maxDepth=6):
        self.vkapi = vkapi
        self.__maxDepth=maxDepth
        self.__answers = list()
        self.__status = 'IDLE'
```

I removed the `isinstance()` expression, it doesn't do anything as you are ignoring the return value of the function call.

Comment: Thank you! But how the right code should look if I use `property` as function, not as decorator?

Comment: Just for being complete, pure getters should work on old-style classes as well...

Comment: @glglgl: ah, indeed; removed the `object` requirement then.

Comment: @user23791: You can add `propertyname = property(getter)` in the class body; for your getters that'd be `answers = property(__getAnswers)` below the definition of the getter.